# fs doesn't get file if i publish module to npm

Tags: node.js, npm, fs

I'm facing a problem when i publish my module to npm.

Here's the file structure:

```
- node_modules
- lib
  -- file.txt
- index.js
- package.json
```

I use it like that:

```
var a = fs.readFileSync('./lib/file.txt');
```

It works in local development. But when i publish my module to npm, it says:

```
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory './lib/file.txt'
```

This error comes from fs, it doesn't get file. Is it about nested node_modules folder?

I mean when i want to test my module in clear folder, i install module:

```
npm install <my-module-name>
```

Creating a test.js file and puting that codes inside it:

```
var myModuleName = require('my-module-name');

var a = myModuleName();

console.log(a);
```

So new structure become:

```
- node_modules
  -- my-module-name
     -- node_modules
     -- lib
        -- file.txt
     -- index.js
     -- package.json
- test.js
```

Any idea?

Comment: Does your `package.json` have `"main": "index.js"`?

Comment: @CodyGustafson  Yes, it already reads index.js file. I guess otherwise it can't get that './lib/file.txt' path, am i right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `fs.readFileSync` is looking for the file relative to the current working directory. Try using `__dirname`:

```
var path = require('path');

var a = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'lib', 'file.txt'));
```